# Automatically generated <a> tags when rendering body content

Tags: 7

My D7 creates anchor tags automatically when '**www**.*****' in text is found.

**Example:**

`<span class="class">www.site.com</span>`

produces

`<span class="class"><a href="www.site.com">www.site.com</a></span>`

but

`<span class="class">site.com</span>`

produces

`<span class="class">site.com</span>`

Corresponding field value stored in DB still has `<span>www.site.com</span>`. Could not any signs of such an action in theme scripts. In known modules neither. Had anyone met something like this? Maybe some guess where to look for?

Comment: Check your text formats, and there uncheck "automatically generate links" or how its called.

Comment: I'm feeling so stupid... Thank you, leymann! What evil soul could create this feature and even make it on by default?

Comment: Evil? You're describing a feature needed for almost every site ever. When people put links in text, usually they want them to be clickable. Your case is the exception, not the norm. Anyways, as Leymann said, look at the text format and remove the 'automatically convert URLs to links' option for that format, or create a new one without that option.

Comment: @Jaypan brakes are needed in all cars. But I doubt you'd want to have one having blocked wheels by default. Features must not silently alter the expected behavior in any kinds of UI including CMS. This feature itself probably IS extremely useful but as for my opinion I'd personally rather make it off by default. From the UX point of view. Anyway I'm not here to argue.

Comment: ...except that you just did.

Comment: Just expressing my opinion. Exact like any other including you. BTW my initial question was totally not about the evilness of this feature if you know what I mean.